# PHP pattern match search system

Tags: php, search, design-patterns

I am trying to have PHP search based on letters entered into a text box. I want it to match a pattern and find the relevant results from the database.

So if I typed in

```
"Jo Smi"
```

It would find results

J`o Smith, Pojo Smithson, Ojo Smith`

How would one achieve this. I know how to get information from the database but not parts of various fields.

The objective is to search through users searching in fields `user_firstname`, `user_lastname` and `user_email`

Any ideas?

Comment: All of these are correct answers: 'like and a wild card', however, simply dropping unvetted text into an SQL statement is potentially a security risk (watcher hints at this with `$escapedTextString`. Read up a little on SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do that directly from your query.

get the text box results and escape them then do

```
SELECT * FROM `database` WHERE `name` REGEXP '{INPUT TEXT HERE}';
```

That should work I think.

Comment: LIKE will be faster but you can get more exact results from REGEXP. Depends on your need

Answer (score 0):

You can do simplistic searching on fields in a database using the LIKE clause:

```
$query = "SELECT Fields FROM Table WHERE TestField LIKE '%".$escapedTextString."%'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a `LIKE` search against an upper-cased version of your search terms.  Don't forget to `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

```
$searchpattern = mysql_real_escape_string(strtoupper("Jo Smi"));
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE UPPER(column) LIKE '%$searchpattern%';");
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello Man  previous answer is good
but you want to know this info

1. get the variable =>    `$name =
   $_GET['name'];`
2. if you want to make it upper case
   use `strtoupper();`
3. if you want to
   make it Lower case use
   `strtolower();`
4. if you want to
   search you should replace = with 
   where like  `where name = $name`   to
   `where name like $name`
5. this info
6. abc%   => variable start with abc   and finish with any thing
7. %abc%  => variable start any thing , contain abc , finish with any thing
8. %abc   => variable start any thing ,finish with abc